# How to use Tinymce or any other Text editor?

Tags: php, html, tinymce, text-editor

Currently i am using Tinymce text editor and added all the details.

**But the problem is :**

I am not able to give space between paragraph.

**For example : When i am entering the below details in the text editor, it shows online like below**

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.

**And I want like this to be shown**

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.

**Screenshot of what i typed**

[image: Text Editor]

Comment: Can you please show us what you typed into the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use paragraph tags:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: Now it displays the content along with <p> tags while viewing online.

Comment: Which tool are you using it and how are you saving your files?

Comment: saving the values in the database and fetching it using php

Comment: It works when I try it on [this online editor](https://codepen.io/tinymce/pen/YydQrY)

Comment: you were right @Brishna, i was just sanitizing the input,that is why it wasn't fetching the html tags...Anyways Thanks